# Generic class type with dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dictionary and I would like the key to be able to be different classes. Right now I'm using:

```
public Dictionary<dynamic,int> CbList = new Dictionary<dynamic,int>();
```

This works but I lose the compile-time checking. Is there a better way?

**EDIT:**

Basically I was wondering if there was a way to have different classes in a dictionary without losing compile-time checking....

The key classes are related in that they have the same contructors...

Comment: "different types" is the opposite of generics.  What checking do you want?

Comment: If you need the key to be of different types what kind of compile-time checking are you expecting?

Comment: What do you propose to do by "using generics"? There are hundreds of ways you could use generics.

Comment: can you set it to "object" or make the classes inherit a common class (which you can set as key)?

Comment: there already is a version of the Dictionary that is generic Dictionary<Tkey, Tvalue>

Comment: you will lose the benefits of using a dictionary.

Comment: A dictionary is indexed, how do you want to compare apples with pears?

Answer (score 0):

If all of the key classes are related, you can create an interface that they all derive from (even if it's just a marker interface):

```
public interface IKey {}
public class KeyOne: IKey {...}
public class KeyTwo: IKey {...}

...
    var dict = new Dictionary<IKey, int>();
...
```

Otherwise, the compiler isn't going to be able to help much.

Comment: Eric, looks like what I've been looking for. Let me try it out a little :)